# How do I skip the filesystem cache when reading a file in Golang?

Tags: linux, caching, go, system-calls

Assume that the contents of the file `Foo.txt` are as follows.

```
Foo Bar Bar Foo
```

Consider the following short program.

```
package main

import "syscall"
import "fmt"


func main() {
    fd, err := syscall.Open("Foo.txt", syscall.O_RDONLY, 0)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed on open: ", err)
    }
    data := make([]byte, 100)
    _, err = syscall.Read(fd, data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed on read: ", err)
    }
    syscall.Close(fd)
}
```

When we run the program above, we get no errors, which is correct behavior.

Now, I modify the `syscall.Open` line to be the following.

```
fd, err := syscall.Open("Foo.txt", syscall.O_RDONLY | syscall.O_SYNC | syscall.O_DIRECT, 0)
```

When I run the program again, I get the following (undesirable) output.

```
Failed on read:  invalid argument
```

**How can I correctly pass the flags `syscall.O_SYNC` and `syscall.O_DIRECT` as specified by the the [`open` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) for skipping the filesystem cache?**

Note that I am using the `syscall` file interface directly instead of the `os` file interface because I could not find a way to pass those flags into the functions provided by `os`, but I am open to solutions that use `os` provided that they work correctly to disable the filesystem cache on reads.

Note also that I am running on `Ubuntu 14.04` with `ext4` as my filesystem.

---

**Update**: I tried to use @Nick Craig-Wood's package in the code below.

```
package main

import "io"
import "github.com/ncw/directio" 
import "os"
import "fmt"


func main() {
    in, err := directio.OpenFile("Foo.txt", os.O_RDONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error on open: ", err)
    }

    block := directio.AlignedBlock(directio.BlockSize)
    _, err = io.ReadFull(in, block)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error on read: ", err)
    }
}
```

The output is the following

```
Error on read:  unexpected EOF
```

Comment: Have you tried to do the open-read-close with those exact arguments in something else than go (C maybe)?
From what I can see on the man page, O_SYNC only affects write operations and O_DIRECT needs some kind of accurately sized (?) buffer in userspace, this might be a go-specific problem, but I'd first try to get that working in C...

Comment: @mrd0ll4r, Actually I ran [this program](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/filebuff/direct_read.c.html) and got the same error `EINVAL` on the C side. So no, it is not go-specific.

Answer (score 6):

You may enjoy my [directio package](https://github.com/ncw/directio) which I made for exactly this purpose.

From the site

This is library for the Go language to enable use of Direct IO under all supported OSes of Go (except openbsd and plan9).

Direct IO does IO to and from disk without buffering data in the OS. It is useful when you are reading or writing lots of data you don't want to fill the OS cache up with.

See here for package docs

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ncw/directio

Comment: I tried to use your package but I get `unexpected EOF` when I try to read.

Comment: @merlin2011 in your example is `"Foo.txt"` bigger than `directio.BlockSize`?

Comment: It is smaller than `directio.BlockSize`.

Comment: @merlin2011 it needs to be bigger than `directio.BlockSize` otherwise you'll get that error.

Answer (score 2):

From the `open` man page, under NOTES:

> The O_DIRECT flag may impose alignment restrictions on the length and address of user-space buffers and the file offset of I/Os.  In Linux alignment restrictions vary by file system and kernel version and might be absent entirely.

So you could have alignment issues, of either the memory or the file offset, or your buffer size could be "wrong". What the alignments and sizes *should* be is not obvious. The man page continues:

> However there is currently no file system-independent interface for an application to discover these restrictions for a given file or file  system.

And even Linus weighs in, in his usual understated manner:

> "The thing that has always disturbed me about O_DIRECT is that the whole interface is just stupid, and was probably designed by a deranged monkey on some serious mind-controlling substances." —Linus

Good luck!

p.s. Stab in the dark: why not read 512 bytes?

Comment: Very interesting insight on the complications of using O_DIRECT. Are you aware of any solution to the question of skipping filesystem cache in Go (even if it involves a completely different route)? I'm also in need of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use fadvice and madvice, but there is no guarantee. both will work more probably with larger files/data, because:

> Partial pages are deliberately preserved on the expectation that it is better to preserve needed memory than to discard unneeded memory.

see the linux source code, what will do something and what not. POSIX_FADV_NOREUSE for example doesn't do anything.

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/fadvise.c#L62

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/madvise.c

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "syscall"

import "golang.org/x/sys/unix"

func main() {
    advise := false
    if len(os.Args) > 1 && os.Args[1] == "-x" {
        fmt.Println("setting file advise")
        advise =true
    }

    data := make([]byte, 100)
    handler, err := os.Open("Foo.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed on open: ", err)
    }; defer handler.Close()

    if advise {
        unix.Fadvise(int(handler.Fd()), 0, 0, 4) // 4 == POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED
    }

    read, err := handler.Read(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed on read: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    if advise {
        syscall.Madvise(data, 4) // 4 == MADV_DONTNEED
    }

    fmt.Printf("read %v bytes\n", read)
}
```

/usr/bin/time -v ./direct -x

```
Command being timed: "./direct -x"
User time (seconds): 0.00
System time (seconds): 0.00
Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.03
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1832
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 2
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 149
Voluntary context switches: 2
Involuntary context switches: 2
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 200
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```